# Creating Christmas Tree using [Matlab]

Tags: xcode, matlab, image-processing

I am looking for a Matlab code to create a Christmas tree
maybe some Triangles above each other and a rectangle with some circles as decoration .

Comment: Provide some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing simpler than that, just use [`fill`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) and [`annotation`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)

```
figure;
hold on;
axis off;

% Strunk
fill([3,3,4,4],[0,1,1,0],[139,69,19]./255,'LineStyle','none')

% Tree
x = [1,6,5,5.5,4.5,5,3.5,2,2.5,1.5,2,1]
y = [1,1,3,3,5,5,8,5,5,3,3,1]
fill(x,y,'g','LineStyle','none')

% Decoration
annotation('ellipse',[0.3,0.5,0.05,0.05],'Color','red','FaceColor','red')
annotation('ellipse',[0.6,0.3,0.05,0.05],'Color','red','FaceColor','red')
annotation('ellipse',[0.55,0.6,0.05,0.05],'Color','red','FaceColor','red')
```

[image: result]